# Populate Matrix in C with rand()

Tags: c, matrix, random, double

I am trying to understand how a Matrix in C works.

I have the following code:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    /* random number generator for matrix dimensions */
    int xDim, yDim;
    srand(time(NULL)); //init. is needed only once
    xDim = (rand() % (10000+1) + 50);
    yDim = (rand() % (10000+1) + 50);

    /* random number generator for matrix contents */
    double* myMatr;
    myMatr = (double *)malloc(xDim * yDim * sizeof(double));
    for(int i=0; i<xDim; i++)
    {
        for(int y=0; y<yDim; y++)
        {
            myMatr[i][y]= (double)rand()/RAND_MAX*100.0;
        }
    }
}
```

However, I am getting this error:

```
test.c:24:13: error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector
myMatr[i][y]= (double)rand()/RAND_MAX*100.0;
```

Comment: `myMatr[i]` is `double`, so apparently you cannot subscript it further.

Comment: `myMatr[i][y]` --> `myMatr[i * yDim + y]`

Comment: `malloc` does not receive the `xDim * yDim` spec, only their product, so there is no way that the memory allocated could be somehow interpreted as a 2-D array by the language.

Comment: `myMatr` not a 2D array but a pointer to `double`. These are two different things.

Comment: As you only define a pointer, how should the compiler be able to make any difference between `myMatr[10][5]` and `myMatr[5][10]`. This can only be done if the limits are all known (except for one dimension)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The minimum change to your code is probably to make `myMatr` into a pointer to an array.

Change:

```
double *myMatr = (double *)malloc(xDim * yDim * sizeof(double));
```

(which is currently spread over two lines in the source) into:

```
double (*myMatr)[yDim] = malloc(xDim * yDim * sizeof(double));
```

The rest of the code shown then works.  You should add `free(myMatr);` before the end, of course.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    srand(time(NULL)); // init. is needed only once

    /* random number generator for matrix dimensions */
    int xDim = (rand() % (10000 + 1) + 50);
    int yDim = (rand() % (10000 + 1) + 50);

    //double *myMatr = (double *)malloc(xDim * yDim * sizeof(double));
    double (*myMatr)[yDim] = malloc(xDim * yDim * sizeof(double));

    /* random number generator for matrix contents */
    for (int i = 0; i < xDim; i++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < yDim; y++)
        {
            myMatr[i][y] = (double)rand() / RAND_MAX * 100.0;
        }
    }

    /* print matrix contents */
    for (int i = 0; i < xDim; i++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < yDim; y++)
            printf("%6.2f", myMatr[i][y]);
        putchar('\n');
    }

    free(myMatr);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In C, `a[x][y]` can mean a couple of things: first, it can mean that `a` is an array of or a pointer to arrays of known length, declared like this:

```
double (*a)[5];
```

That is, `a` points to arrays of 5 doubles. Since this size is known ahead of time, you can allocate a big block and do the double indexing on it. But this won't work if you need to determine the size of both indices at runtime. In that case, you have no choice but to declare `a` as an array of pointers, and allocate this array and each of its sub-arrays separately:

```
double **a;
a = malloc(xDim * sizeof(double *));
for (int i = 0; i < xDim; i += 1) {
    a[i] = malloc(yDim * sizeof(double));
}
```

Now, `a[x][y]` means "find the xth pointer in array a, then find the yth double in the array it points to".